# Call to IEnumerable.Count() takes multiple seconds

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a little windows service which should delete all occurrences of a certain file name in certain folders.
All this code runs in the `elapsed-handler` of the timer (intervall=10s).

When the service is running I can recognize a CPU increase up to 20% used by that service, so I examined my code, put some trace commands in it and found out that executing the handler took about 3-4 seconds for nothing.

I narrowed it down to the following piece of code: `allReporterFiles.Count()`.
It's calling the method `Count()` of this `IEnumerable` and this call takes 3-4 seconds.

My project is setup for .NET 4.7.2. Is this a framework bug or what?

```
 var files1 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirSwReporter, swReporterFileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
 var files2 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirSwReporter2, swReporterFileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

 var allReporterFiles = files1.Union(files2);

 var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var fileCount = allReporterFiles.Count(); // <--- takes ~3.5 seconds
 sw.Stop();

 Trace.WriteLine($"KillChromeSoftwareReporterTool completed in: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds}ms or  {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}sec");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is this a framework bug or what?

It's an issue with your understanding of LINQ's deferred execution, I suspect.

`allReporterFiles` is just an `IEnumerable<string>`. Calling `Count()` means iterating over it - which in turn means the `Union` code iterating over `files1` and `files2`. I suspect you have an awful lot of files.

The way to tell that is to measure how long it takes to iterate over `files1` and `files2` separately. One easy way to do that is to call `ToList()`. For example:

```cs
// The use of ToList forces the result to be materialized, rather than using deferred
// execution.

var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var files1 = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(dirSwReporter, swReporterFileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .ToList();
var files1Time = stopwatch.Elapsed;

stopwatch.Restart();
var files2 = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(dirSwReporter2, swReporterFileName, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .ToList();
var files2Time = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

Then log `files1Time` and `files2Time`. Now that the content is in two lists, counting the `Union` won't involve any IO. It will still need to basically create a `HashSet<string>` as it goes, in order to avoid returning the same value more than once, but it will be much, much quicker.

This approach won't be any faster overall - and will use more memory - but it'll make it obvious whether most of the time is in searching in `dirSwReporter` or `dirSwReporter2`, which may be enough to help you optimize.

Comment: First stopwatch: 0.7ms, 
Second stopwatch: 3,5 seconds.
File-Count is currently 0, so nothing to work on...
But the second `Directory.EnumerateFiles` has to search a deeper sub-directory tree, I guess that's the problem here then, cause both `EnumerateFiles` return `0`.

Comment: Don't we need `stopwatch.Restart()` instead of `Reset()`?

Comment: @Knoop: Not if it hasn't been stopped, I believe. (I don't think Reset stops it; it just sets the elapsed time to 0.)

Comment: From the documentation "Use Reset to stop any interval measurement in progress and clear the elapsed time value." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.reset?view=netcore-2.2). If used like this `files2Time` will always be `0`(fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AoNNpA)

Comment: @Knoop: You're absolutely right - thanks, will fix.

Answer (score 2):

The information about the deferred execution is buried in the Remarks sections at .NET Framework 4.7 [Directory.EnumerateFiles Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.7)'s doco.

> The `EnumerateFiles` and `GetFiles` methods differ as follows: When you use `EnumerateFiles`, you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is returned; when you use `GetFiles`, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, `EnumerateFiles` can be more efficient.

The part about efficiency is obviously irrelevant for your context since you're calling `Count` on the result which requires full enumeration.

---

BTW. .NET Framework 4.8 [Directory.EnumerateFiles Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.8)'s doco states:

> The returned collection is not cached; each call to the GetEnumerator on the collection will start a new enumeration.

Comment: Actually a stupid question of mine, cause the second `EnumerateFiles` which takes 3.5s has to search a ton of files and folders, that's why it was slow...but sometimes it gets late ;-)